# Probability that $x^2 > 4y$, where $x$ and $y$ are randomly chosen.

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with uniform distributions over $[0,1]$. What is $P(X^2 > 4Y)$?

I've made the obvious conclusion that this is equivalent to the area of the subset of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ where $f(x,y) = x^2 - 4y$ is positive, but I don't know what to do from there. I set $f = 0$ and found $x = 2y$ (considering only positive $y$ of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2-4y>0\implies y<{x^2\over 4}$.

Integration over $[0,1]$ gives $\int_0^1{x^2\over4}dx={1\over12}$

Comment: Why did you integrate? Note sure where the result is coming from.

Comment: Given an area $=1$ rectangle $R$ and an area$={1\over 12}$ shape $S$ inside the rectangle, what is the possibility that when you throw a darts in $R$, it lands inside $S$?